# Sumar N minutos a una hora en javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Estoy haciendo un horario con angular y tengo un formGroup con un la lista de dias de la semana con una hora de apertura y de cierre

```
this._formBuilder.group({

  schedulesDays: ['0'],
  schedules:  this._formBuilder.group({
    monday: ["Horario"],
    tuesday: ["Horario"],
    wednesday: ["Horario"],
    thursday:[ "Horario"],
    friday: ["Horario"],
    saturday: ["Horario"],
    sunday: ["Horario"],
    mondayHours: this._formBuilder.group({
      mondayHoursOpen: "00:00",
      mondayHoursClose: "23:59",
      configHorarios: this._formBuilder.array([])
    }),
    tuesdayHours: this._formBuilder.group({
      tuesdayHoursOpen: "00:00",
      tuesdayHoursClose:"23:59",
      configHorarios: this._formBuilder.array([])
    }),
    wednesdayHours: this._formBuilder.group({
      wednesdayHoursOpen: "00:00",
      wednesdayHoursClose: "23:59",
      configHorarios: this._formBuilder.array([])
    }),
    thursdayHours:this._formBuilder.group({
      thursdayHoursOpen: "00:00",
      thursdayHoursClose: "23:59",
      configHorarios: this._formBuilder.array([])
    }),
    fridayHours: this._formBuilder.group({
      fridayHoursOpen: "00:00",
      fridayHoursClose:"23:59",
      configHorarios: this._formBuilder.array([])
    }),
    saturdayHours: this._formBuilder.group({
      saturdayHoursOpen: "00:00",
      saturdayHoursClose: "23:59",
      configHorarios: this._formBuilder.array([])
    }),
    sundayHours: this._formBuilder.group({
      sundayHoursOpen: "00:00",
      sundayHoursClose: "23:59",
      configHorarios: this._formBuilder.array([])
    })
  
}),

});
```

necesito que al darle a un boton pueda setear la hora de cierre + 1 minuto adicional, es decir
si al presionar el boton tengo la hora de cierre como 11:00 luego que presione el boton sumar un minuto adicional y que apareza "11:01"

en palabras mas cortas como le puedo sumar 1 minuto a una hora por ejemplo "10:00" y que luego sea "10:01"

***ya al presionar el boton obtengo la hora del cierre del dia pero no se si es posible sumarle el minuto porque son strings***

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date)?

Comment: intente con new Date("11:00") pero dice que es un invalida, porque esas horas realmente son un strings

Comment: Por supuesto que no es un formato válido, para ello puedes usar [`.setHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) y [`.setMinutes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMinutes)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo montando el formato de fecha, después sumas un minuto (javascript se encargará de reajustar la hora cuando pases por encima de `59` o por debajo de `00`) y posteriormente te vuelves a quedar con hora y minutos:

```js
/* Precargo del DOM todo lo necesario */
let b_mas = document.getElementById("b_mas");
let b_menos = document.getElementById("b_menos");
let hora = document.getElementById("hora");

/* Función que suma o resta minutos */
function tiempo(minutos) {
  let tiempo;
  tiempo = new Date("2000-01-01T" + hora.value + ":00Z");
  /* Si es una fecha inválida restauramos a 00:00 */
  if (isNaN(tiempo)) {
    tiempo = new Date("2000-01-01T00:00:00Z");
  }
  /* Operamos con los minutos */
  tiempo.setMinutes(tiempo.getMinutes() + minutos);
  /* Nos quedamos solo con hora y minuto */
  hora.value = tiempo.toISOString().substr(11, 5);
}

/* Asigno a cada botón sumar o restar un minuto */
b_mas.addEventListener("click", function() { tiempo(+1); });
b_menos.addEventListener("click", function() { tiempo(-1); });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="hora" value="11:00" />
<button id="b_mas">+</button>
<button id="b_menos">-</button>
```